# Error when making a fortran MPI_Allgather code

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have a Fortran code that compiles okay, but returns error when executing this `MPI_Allgather` routine

```
call MPI_Allgather(rank, 1, MPI_INTEGER,            
                   allranks(0:np-1), np, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_COMM_WORLD, erro)
```

`rank` is an integer variable, `allranks` is an integer array with `np` positions labeled from `0` to `np-1`

The error is

```
malloc.c:4630: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long)(size) >= (unsigned long)(nb)' failed.
```

Does anyone have an idea of the cause of the error? If so, how I can solve this?

Comment: The error means that internal data structures of malloc are corrupted. Which is usually out-of-bounds array access or using uninitialized objects or something similar (probably this happened before the MPI_Allgather call).

Answer (score 2):

The 5th argument states the number of elements to receive from any process. That is in your case this should be 1. That is recvcount should state how many entries you expect from each process. The MPI standard states:

> The type signature associated with *sendcount, sendtype* at a process must be equal to the type signature associated with *recvcount, recvtype* at any other process.